# Health call to get the number of free mysql connections

Tags: connection, node-mysql

I am using node-mysql library to connect to mysql. Sometimes when the number of connections reaches the connectionLimit, then the mysql connections are not created unless someone releases it. I want to monitor 'the connection not closed' use case, hence i want to write a health call to check the number of free connections at any point in time. But the Pool.js doesnot expose free connection count. Is there any way of doing it other than 1. maintaining my own count 2. Creating a wrapper on the existing library.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it myself, but maybe something like this would work for you:

```js
app.get('/connections', (req, res) => {

  const sql = `SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = 'Threads_connected'`;

  pool.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err)
      throw err;

    return res.send({ numConnections: result[0].value });

  });

});
```